# why nuget could not add protobuf-net 668 reference to visual studio project automatically

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, protobuf-net

I use nuget in my vs project to download dependencies, Mysql.Data and Protbuf-net,

the packages.config file is under the same directory whith .sln file, which contains :

```
<packages>  
<package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.9" targetFramework="net40-client" />  
<package id="protobuf-net" version="2.0.0.668" targetFramework="net40-client" /> 
</packages>
```

when restored packages, there is a new folder packages which contains MySql.Data and protobuf-net, but
only MySql.data reference is added into project Reference. I know I can manually add the reference to it, but

the issue is that when use travis-cl to build my solution, It will fail

Answer (score 0):

NuGet package restore will not modify your project. If your project is missing the protobuf-net reference you will need to modify your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the package references into project automatically, I suggest you put the packages.config file to the same directory with .csproj file.

Then reinstall them with following command after restore packages. I have tested it in my side, when running this command in Package Manager Console window, the package references will be added into project automatically.

> Update-Package -reinstall

And you also can choose add the references manually.